# What could I do to store a case class consisting of aggregates into a non-aggregate data type

Tags: scala

I have the following `Case Class`

case class data(f:String, a:String)

My model contains a list of the above case class

```
case class mymodel {
...
md:List[data],
...
}
```

I have to store the `md` in a database but the database library doesn't support aggregates like list, set, UDTs etc. It supports basic types like test, int etc.

What could I do to store the `md` in the database.

I am thinking of creating two fields in the table

```
f: text
a:text
```

and then store all `md.f` as concatenated string delimited by some character in `f`. I could do the same for `md.a`. The problem (though not a big one) is that `f` and `a` then cannot contain the delimiting character.

Is the above approach my best option or is there some other approach I could follow?

Comment: If there is no support for any collection type in this database library like an Array, Set, List, Map, etc. then you will have to serialize the data in some way, yes.  The best serialization would probably be a String containing your data delimited by some known character, exactly as you suggest.

Comment: What database are you using, because this is super relevant.

Comment: I am using Cassandra which supports aggregates but I am using ScalarDB as the library to interact with it. ScalarDB provides ACID support for Cassandra